# Get data from nested json and display using Vue-Multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Basically what I want to achieve is GET data from server and display the data in the nested json to display in Multiselect, [Vue-Multiselect](https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect)

After displaying, i'm able to add new tags to it if i want (Being able to update it).

I'm able to get the objects from the nested json to display in multiselect, but I'm not sure how to customize it to only show the name.

**Current behaviour:**
[image]

---

**So expected behaviour would be, only Sofa, Table and Chair should be shown in the multiselect:**
[image]

Is there a way for me to only display like the picture above?

---

After implementing @Ikbel's way of getting the json object and showing only the required name. Now I have another problem which is I get duplicates of the options whenever I add a new tag to it.

**This is my Vue Code:**

```
   <template>
       <multiselect :multiple="true"
       v-model="data.subCategoryNames"
       :hide-selected="true"
       :selected="data.subCategoryNames"
       :options="computedSubCategoryNames"
       :taggable="true"
       @tag="addTag"
        >
        </multiselect>
  </template>


  methods: {
    addTag (newTag) {
      // this.options.push(newTag)
      this.data.subCategoryNames.push(newTag)
    }
  }



computed: {
    computedSubCategoryNames () {
      return this.allSubCategoryNames.map((item) => {
        this.options.push(item.subCategoryName)
        this.data.subCategoryNames.push(item.subCategoryName)
        return item.subCategoryName
      })
    }
  }
```

**Which shows this:**
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, I answered your question below, take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok @mary. Here is a better solution. Simply add `label="subCategoryName"` to your multiselect component to make it show `subCategoryName` only instead of the whole object. So no need for a computed property.

`track-by` should be used to avoid duplicate values.

Here is a working example.

```js
let Multiselect = VueMultiselect.Multiselect

let vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: {
      subCategoryNames: [],
      options: [
        {subCategoryName: 'Chair', count: 2},
        {subCategoryName: 'Table', count: 5},
      ],
    },
  },   
 
  components: { 
    Multiselect 
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.0"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">


<div id="app">        
  <multiselect :multiple="true"
       v-model="data.subCategoryNames"
       :hide-selected="true"
       :selected="data.subCategoryNames"
       :options="data.options"
       :taggable="true"
       label="subCategoryName"
       track-by="subCategoryName"
        >
        </multiselect>
        
   {{data.subCategoryNames}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Ikbel , using `label="subCategoryName"` and `track-by="subCategoryName"` worked for my case! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed property to extract the subcategory names. Here is how you can do it.

Bind your multiselect `options` to a computed `subCategoryNames` instead. Let's call it `computedSubCategoryNames`, and use the array method `map()` to extract `subCategoryName` from `subCategoryNames`. Here is an example:

```
<multiselect :options="computedSubCategoryNames">
</multiselect>
```

And in define `computedSubCategoryNames`:

```
computed: {
  // Returns ['Chair', 'Sofa', 'Table']
  computedSubCategoryNames() {
    return this.subCategoryNames.map(function(item) {
      return item.subCategoryName
    }) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ikbel , I used your method and it works! I have also added additional code to it so it works 100%.   `this.options.push(item.subCategoryName)`
        `this.data.subCategoryNames.push(item.subCategoryName)`

Comment: Hi @Ikbel , after adding this line `this.options.push(item.subCategoryName)` i realized i have another problem which is, whenever i want to add a new tag, my options will then be "sofa,table,chair,TEST1,sofa,table,chair". Is there a way to stop the re-pushing of options from the computed method?

Comment: Hi @mary. Can you post your Vue methods so I can look into that. I think that there's a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below URL, onether approach to show multiselect drop down in android
https://asnehal.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/multi-select-drop-down-list-in-android/